# How do I add items to Windows Explorer New menu?

Tags: windows-explorer

How do I add items to Windows Explorer right-click context menu called New?

Comment: Should take this over to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP it appears they are registry entries. On my machine it's all listed under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Discardable\PostSetup\ShellNew
```

Comment: That key also exists on Windows7, so I'm guessing it'll be good on Vista too.

Answer (score 0):

Sample using ".sql" files.

1. Start -> Run
2. %userprofile%\Templates
3. Copy NewProc.sql
4. Edit the registry

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.sql\ShellNew]
Value Name = FileName
Value Data = NewProc.sql

Seems kinda kludgy and to only support one new item per file type, so I'm on the lookout for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this anyone still needs this but you can add stuff to the new menu like this:
start cmd as admin
type the command
`reg ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<extension name>\ShellNew`
and than use
`reg ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<extension name>\ShellNew /v NullFile /t REG_SZ /d 1`
Note that the  must have a ". in front of it e.g. .txt or .bat etc.
Hope this helps. If it doesn't help, you can also look here:
https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-create-new-add-items/